# Hbase update only when changed

Tags: hbase, updates

I've got a use case where I need to check whether Hbase Puts are actually writing changed values or not.

I did my homework and know of the checkAndPut method but that does not really solve the problem:

- I got a value client side which may be a change to the most current value in Hbase, or not
- If it is not a change I would rather not write it at all
- With checkAndPut I can only check for equality of a client side value and a server side value
- checkAndPut will execute the Put if it is true

I can think of 2 solutions, both not very appealing:

1. Performing a pre Put check client side, after getting the latest value from HBase (2 round trips)
2. Doing the checkAndPut as above, when it returns false, resubmit the Put without a checkAndPut (2 round trips, plus a rewrite of non-changed value for all succeeded checkAndPut s)

Is there a way to turn the checkAndPut logic around and execute the Put immediately only if the comparison fails? Or even a different approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of someone who is still looking : [`HTable#checkAndPut`](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#checkAndPut(byte[],%20byte[],%20byte[],%20org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter.CompareOp,%20byte[],%20org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put))

Effective from Hbase version : `0.98.7, 0.99.1`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the new checkandPut which is introduced in Hbase 1.1.8

if you want the different value to be updated only you can use the comparator NOT_EQUAL

```
public void write(final byte[] row, final byte[] family, final byte[] qualifier, final byte[] value, final Put put) throws IOException {
 CompareFilter.CompareOp compareOp = CompareFilter.CompareOp.NOT_EQUAL;
  this.table.checkAndPut(row,family,qualifier,compareOp,value,put);
}
```